# need xsl that transforms the file in required format

Tags: xml, xslt

Having trouble fromatting the xml.
Need the below xml to be formatted to the mentioned format.
need the values to be transalated to lower case too.

Input XML

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <serviceConfig>
     <consumer id="1">
       <cn>A</cn>
       <cn>B</cn>
       <cn>C</cn>
     </consumer>
     <consumer id="2">
       <cn>D</cn>
       <cn>E</cn>
     </consumer>
     <consumer id="3">
      <cn>F</cn>
      </consumer>
     <consumer id="4">
       <cn>G</cn>
       <cn>H</cn>
       <cn>I</cn>
     </consumer>
     <consumer id="5">
      <cn>J</cn>
      <cn>K</cn>
      <cn>M</cn>
    </consumer>
</serviceConfig>`
```

Required output

```
<serviceConfig>
   <consumer id="1">a</consumer>
   <consumer id="1">b</consumer>
   <consumer id="1">c</consumer>
   <consumer id="2">d</consumer>
   <consumer id="2">e</consumer>
   <consumer id="3">f</consumer>
   <consumer id="4">g</consumer>
   <consumer id="4">h</consumer>
   <consumer id="4">i</consumer>
   <consumer id="5">j</consumer>
   <consumer id="5">k</consumer>
   <consumer id="5">m</consumer>
</serviceConfig>
```

using xsl version 1.0

When i am using below xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<serviceConfig>
<xsl:for-each select="//consumer/cn">
<consumer>
<xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select = "//consumer/@id"/></xsl:attribute>
<xsl:value-of select = "."/>
</consumer>
</xsl:for-each>
</serviceConfig>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

all my id are being returned from the first occurrence.but need the corresponding id for that element

```
<serviceConfig>
   <consumer id="1">A</consumer>
   <consumer id="1">B</consumer>
   <consumer id="1">C</consumer>
   <consumer id="1">D</consumer>
   <consumer id="1">E</consumer>
   <consumer id="1">F</consumer>
   <consumer id="1">G</consumer>
   <consumer id="1">H</consumer>
   <consumer id="1">I</consumer>
   <consumer id="1">J</consumer>
   <consumer id="1">K</consumer>
   <consumer id="1">M</consumer>
</serviceConfig>
```

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Please try  the following XSLT.

It is using a so called *Identity Transform* pattern.

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<serviceConfig>
    <consumer id="1">
        <cn>A</cn>
        <cn>B</cn>
        <cn>C</cn>
    </consumer>
    <consumer id="2">
        <cn>D</cn>
        <cn>E</cn>
    </consumer>
    <consumer id="3">
        <cn>F</cn>
    </consumer>
    <consumer id="4">
        <cn>G</cn>
        <cn>H</cn>
        <cn>I</cn>
    </consumer>
    <consumer id="5">
        <cn>J</cn>
        <cn>K</cn>
        <cn>M</cn>
    </consumer>
</serviceConfig>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="consumer">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="cn">
        <consumer id="{../@id}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </consumer>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<serviceConfig>
  <consumer id="1">A</consumer>
  <consumer id="1">B</consumer>
  <consumer id="1">C</consumer>
  <consumer id="2">D</consumer>
  <consumer id="2">E</consumer>
  <consumer id="3">F</consumer>
  <consumer id="4">G</consumer>
  <consumer id="4">H</consumer>
  <consumer id="4">I</consumer>
  <consumer id="5">J</consumer>
  <consumer id="5">K</consumer>
  <consumer id="5">M</consumer>
</serviceConfig>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your stylesheet will work as expected, if you change:

```
<xsl:value-of select = "//consumer/@id"/><
```

to:

```
<xsl:value-of select = "../@id"/>
```

See: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#path-abbrev